# Gradle: How to include additional package to war?

Tags: java, gradle, war, gretty

I have package in root of gradle module. How can I include it in war build using gradle & gretty?

It's non-java package, named 'frontend'.

Comment: A package as in... a Java package, containing source code that needs to be compiled? Or something else. Don't hesitate to make your question longer than one line.

Comment: probably (hopefully) he means a JAR library compiled from his own source code.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [the documentation of the War task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.bundling.War.html).

As you can see, it has a `from()` method allowing to add a source directory.

The [war plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html) has an example showing its usage

```
war {
    from 'frontend'
}
```